# WinRT: How do you present a BitmapIcon without scaling?

Tags: bitmap, windows-runtime

I'm trying to present a BitmapIcon on a tile as part of the metadata.  However, when I use:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Customer"/>
            <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///DarkBond.LicenseManager.License/Assets/Medium/Folder.png"/>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
```

I get:

[image: Blurry Icon]

How do I force this image to use the native resolution (it's a 32x32 bitmap).  In WPF, I would use the 'Stretch="None" attribute.  What's the equivalent in WinRT?

Comment: Are you developing a uwp app? I didn't find the `BitmapIcon` in [tile schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212859.aspx), just `image`.

Comment: wut are you talking about?  A 'Tile' is any graphic element in a GridView.  I've updated the XAML to be more specific.